# Adding parallax to one img in the div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to add a parallax effect to 1 image in the `div`, like iPhones floating on Apple's website. I presume that it is parallax effect.

So here is the markup. Nothing fancy, my first parallax though..

```js
var ypos, image;

function parallax() {
  image = document.getElementById('image');
  ypos = window.pageYOffset;
  image.style.top = ypos * -1 + 'px';
}
window.addEventListener('scroll', parallax);
```

```css
   * {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     font-family: Lucida Grande;
   }
   h1 {
     font-weight: 500;
     text-align: center;
     margin: 15px 0;
   }
   p {
     font-size: 23px;
     font-weight: 100;
   }
   body,
   html {
     min-height: 100%;
     width: 100%;
   }
   .intro {
     background-color: #e8e1d7;
     max-height: 700px;
     overflow: auto;
     z-index: -1;
     overflow-y: hidden;
   }
   .left {
     float: left;
     width: 60%;
     z-index: 1;
     padding: 100px 140px;
     box-sizing: border-box;
   }
   .intro .img {
     float: left;
     width: 40%;
   }
   .intro .img img {
     z-index: 1;
     bottom: -200px;
     position: relative;
     height: 500px;
   }
   .next {
     background-color: white;
     z-index: 1;
     position: relative;
     height: 790px;
   }
```

```html
<div class="intro">
  <div class="left">
    <h1>This is iPhone 5</h1>
    <p>here we present you world's most advanced piece of technology ever! all the iphones come in standard silver and black (space grey color). The 8 MP camera makes shooting photos more vibrant! have a look to our new phone at your nearest apple store
      now!</p>
  </div>
  <div class="img">
    <img src="http://pngimg.com/upload/iphone_PNG5736.png" id="image" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="next">

</div>
```

please see the snippet in full page view

Comment: `image = getElementById('image');` should be `image = document.getElementById('image');`

Comment: Also `y.pos * -1 + 'px';` should be `ypos * -1 + 'px';`

Comment: I actually want the phone(object) to slowly slide upwards when we scroll down, but here the image is shifting upwards immediately when we scroll up! can you help me with that?

Comment: You should explain the problem *in the question*, and fix the obvious typos first (your [JavaScript console](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers) would have told you about the two things I mentioned above). As it is, you have no real question, and a code sample that doesn't demonstrate anything (since it won't run). See [ask] for more suggestions on writing a question that's likely to get answered.

Comment: ok, I've changed it, please help me now, I'm  really curious of how they do it! I want that iPhone to slowly slide top the top as we scroll to the bottom of the page!

Comment: [Maybe look for parallax tutorials](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=parallax+scrolling+tutorial&t=ffab&ia=web)